# Proguard Optimization Explanation

Tags: optimization, proguard

Can someone explain to me in layman's terms the differences between these optimization options?

I read through http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/optimizations.html but I'm fairly new to Proguard and non of the info there makes sense to me.

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/simplification/cast

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
```